# submit hdinsight Spark job using IntelliJ IDEA failure

Tags: azure, apache-spark, intellij-idea, azure-hdinsight

When I submit hdinsight Spark job using IntelliJ IDEA Community
Error :

```
Failed to submit application to spark cluster.
Exception : Forbidden. Attached Azure DataLake Store is not supported in Automated login model.
Please logout first and try Interactive login model
```

Comment: even i am login using interactive mode

Comment: added tags, formatting improved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expcetion are shown when selecting `Automated` option in `Azure Sign In` dialog and sumitting a Spark Job into a Cluster which store is Azure DataLake Store. So, use the `Interactive` option for the cluster, please.

The Automated login model is only used for the Azure Blob Store Cluster.

You could try the following steps:

1. Sign out from the Azure Explorer firstly
2. Sign in with the `Interactive` option
3. Select the Spark cluster with Azure DataLake Store in Spark job submission dialog and submit the job.

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-toolkit-for-intellij-sign-in-instructions for more instructions.

[Update]

If your account have no permission to access that Azure DataLake Store, the same exception will be thrown.

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-security-overview

The compiled Spark Job will be uploaded to the ADL folder `adl://<adls>.azuredatalakestore.net/<cluster attached folder>/SparkSubmission/**`. So the user needs 
permission to write. You'd better to ask admin to check your role access.

Comment: Thanks a lot it's working now, i don't have permission on folder so it's give error

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replay, i am able to submit my Spark Job without any problem, i need to Debug using Remote Debugging options that will error out please she error in above